# Mapping already-mapped Interface Collection using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I have the following interfaces for some DTOs:

```
public interface IGalleryView    
{
    ICollection<IGalleryImageView> Images { get; set; }
}

public interface IGalleryImageView 
{
     // Some simple properties
}
```

and the following concrete types:

```
public class GalleryView : IGalleryView 
{
    public GalleryView() {
        Images = new List<IGalleryImageView>();
    } 
    public ICollection<IGalleryImageView> Images { get; set; }
}

public class GalleryImageView : IGalleryImageView 
{
}
```

These are being mapped from my EF POCO Entities.  These entities look like:

```
public partial class Gallery {
    // Constructors removed for brevity
    public virtual ICollection<GalleryImage> Images { get; set; }
}

public partial class GalleryImage {
    public virtual Gallery Gallery { get; set; }
}
```

I am mapping these in AutoMapper as follows:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<GalleryImage, IGalleryImageView>()
            .As<GalleryImageView>();

AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Gallery, IGalleryView>()
            .As<GalleryView>();
```

However, I am getting the following error:

> The following property on Contracts.IGalleryImageView cannot be mapped: 
>       Images
>   Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type Contracts.IGalleryImageView.
>   Context:
>       Mapping to property Images from Model.GalleryImage to Contracts.IGalleryImageView
>       Mapping to property Images from System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Model.GalleryImage, Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] to System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[Contracts.IGalleryImageView, Contracts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>       Mapping from type Model.Gallery to Contracts.IGalleryView
>   Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException' was thrown.

I'm not sure what the issue is here, as I have specified maps for the conversion. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is there any relevant code missing? I added the code from above to a test project, and do not get an exception calling Mapper.Map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the above code is OK and the problem isn't related to the hierarchy, BUT a map needs to be created between the original source object and the object in the `As` method.  For the Gallery mapping above, it would be:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Gallery, GalleryView>(); // Additional line here needed
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<GalleryView, IGalleryViewView>().As<GalleryViewView>();
```